# pyzmail: use a loop variable to get a single raw message

Tags: python

First, I should say, I don't really know much about computer programming, but I find Python fairly easy to use for automating simple tasks, thanks to Al Sweigart's book, "Automate the boring stuff."

I want to collect email text bodies. I'm trying to move homework to email to save paper. I thought I could do that by getting the numbers of the unseen mails and just looping through that. If I try that, the IDLE3 shell just becomes unresponsive, ctrl c does nothing, I have to restart the shell.

Question: Why can't I just use a loop variable in server.fetch()??

```
for msgNum in unseenMessages:
    rawMessage = server.fetch([msgNum], ['BODY[]', 'FLAGS'])
```

It seems you need an actual number like 57, not msgNum, in there, or it won't work.

After looking at various questions and answers here on SO, the following works for me. I suppose it collects all the email bodies in one swoop.

```
import pyzmail
import pprint
from imapclient import IMAPClient

server = IMAPClient('imap.qq.com', use_uid=True, ssl=True)
server.login('myEmail@foxmail.com', 'myIMAPpassword')
select_info = server.select_folder('Inbox')
unseenMessages = server.search(['UNSEEN'])
rawMessage = server.fetch(unseenMessages, ['BODY[]', 'FLAGS']) 
for msgNum in unseenMessages:
    message = pyzmail.PyzMessage.factory(rawMessage[msgNum][b'BODY[]'])
    text = message.text_part.get_payload().decode(message.text_part.charset)
    print('Text' + str(msgNum) + ' = ')
    print(text)
```

Comment: pyzmail seems to be outdated and not maintained anymore. Anyway, recent versions of [imaplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html) standard module works quite well in Python. Could you consider to give it a try?

Comment: I tried with imaplib but it seems more complicated that pyzmail. I am not really a computer person. Could you help me alter my code to use imaplib?

Comment: Sure, I'll write code for you a bit later

Comment: I've found this [gist](https://gist.github.com/robulouski/7441883) with nice and clean code and a [page](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/2875/imaplib.IMAP4_SSL) with many helping examples.

Comment: The main difference between `imaplib` and `pyzmail` is pyzmail is all-in-one package with parsing and all client-server communication. But these packages are splitted into different packages in standard library. Basically, they both provided almost the same functionality and with the same methods.

Comment: Thank you very much, very useful links! I'll try just using imaplib.

Comment: May I put them as an answer?

Comment: Of course, I will be glad if you do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this [gist](https://gist.github.com/robulouski/7441883) with nice and clean code and a [page](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/2875/imaplib.IMAP4_SSL) with many helping examples

The main difference between API of `imaplib` and `pyzmail` is pyzmail is all-in-one package with parsing and all client-server communication. But these packages are splitted into different packages in standard library. Basically, they both provided almost the same functionality and with the same methods.

As an additional important note here, `pyzmail` looks quite abandoned.

To save a useful code from that gist, I copy it here as it is with very small modifications like extracting `main` function (note, it's for Python 3):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# Very basic example of using Python 3 and IMAP to iterate over emails in a
# gmail folder/label.  This code is released into the public domain.
#
# This script is example code from this blog post:
# http://www.voidynullness.net/blog/2013/07/25/gmail-email-with-python-via-imap/
#
# This is an updated version of the original -- modified to work with Python 3.4.
#
import sys
import imaplib
import getpass
import email
import email.header
import datetime


EMAIL_ACCOUNT = "notatallawhistleblowerIswear@gmail.com"

# Use 'INBOX' to read inbox.  Note that whatever folder is specified, 
# after successfully running this script all emails in that folder 
# will be marked as read.
EMAIL_FOLDER = "Top Secret/PRISM Documents"


def process_mailbox(M):
    """
    Do something with emails messages in the folder.  
    For the sake of this example, print some headers.
    """

    rv, data = M.search(None, "ALL")
    if rv != 'OK':
        print("No messages found!")
        return

    for num in data[0].split():
        rv, data = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        if rv != 'OK':
            print("ERROR getting message", num)
            return

        msg = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
        hdr = email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header(msg['Subject']))
        subject = str(hdr)
        print('Message %s: %s' % (num, subject))
        print('Raw Date:', msg['Date'])
        # Now convert to local date-time
        date_tuple = email.utils.parsedate_tz(msg['Date'])
        if date_tuple:
            local_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
                email.utils.mktime_tz(date_tuple))
            print ("Local Date:", \
                local_date.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S"))

def main(host, login, folder):
    with imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host) as M:
        rv, data = M.login(login, getpass.getpass())

        print(rv, data)

        rv, mailboxes = M.list()
        if rv == 'OK':
            print("Mailboxes:")
            print(mailboxes)

        rv, data = M.select(folder)
        if rv == 'OK':
            print("Processing mailbox...\n")
            process_mailbox(M)
        else:
            print("ERROR: Unable to open mailbox ", rv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main('imap.gmail.com', EMAIL_ACCOUNT, EMAIL_FOLDER)
    except imaplib.IMAP4.error as e:
        print('Error while processing mailbox:', e)
        sys.exit(1)
```